# I have a crash when add DFP to my app android

Tags: android, android-studio, admob, google-dfp, google-ad-manager

I try add DFP Banner Ads to my app , All steps have been applied in https://developers.google.com/ad-manager/mobile-ads-sdk/android/banner .

but if I open my app it crash

crash:

```
        java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.ads.doubleclick.PublisherAdView.loadAd(com.google.android.gms.ads.doubleclick.PublisherAdRequest)' on a null object reference
        at com.englishprofor.all.fragment.FragmentCategory.onCreateView(FragmentCategory.java:61)
```

FragmentCategory.class

```
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.LinearLayout;
    import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
    import com.englishprofor.all.AppController;
    import com.englishprofor.all.Constant;
    import com.englishprofor.all.R;
    import com.englishprofor.all.activity.MainActivity;
    import com.englishprofor.all.activity.SettingActivity;
    import com.englishprofor.all.helper.CircleImageView;
    import com.englishprofor.all.helper.SettingsPreferences;
    import com.englishprofor.all.model.Category;
    import com.englishprofor.all.model.SubCategory;
    import com.google.android.gms.ads.doubleclick.PublisherAdRequest;
    import com.google.android.gms.ads.doubleclick.PublisherAdView;
    import com.google.android.gms.ads.doubleclick.*;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class FragmentCategory extends Fragment {
        private static final String TAG = "FragmentCategory";
    Context con ;
        private RecyclerView recyclerView;
        private View view;
        ArrayList<Category> mListItem;
        //AdView mAdView;
        private PublisherAdView mPublisherAdView;

        TextView empty_msg, tvTitle;
        CoordinatorLayout layout;
        ImageView back, setting;
        public static ArrayList<Category> categoryList;
        public static ArrayList<SubCategory> subCatList;


        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_category, container, false);
            mPublisherAdView = view.findViewById(R.id.publisherAdView);
            PublisherAdRequest adRequest = new PublisherAdRequest.Builder().build();
    mPublisherAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

fragment_category.xml

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/background">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
           >
            <include layout="@layout/actionbar_layout"/>


        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/category_recycleview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout"
            android:layout_above="@+id/banner_AdView"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtblanklist"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:visibility="gone" />

            <com.google.android.gms.ads.doubleclick.PublisherAdView
                android:id="@+id/banner_AdView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                ads:adSize="BANNER"
                ads:adUnitId="/6499/example/banner">
            </com.google.android.gms.ads.doubleclick.PublisherAdView>

                </RelativeLayout>
            </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

please help me , I want enable DFP in my app

thanks for all

Answer (score 0):

You got a wrong id of view in below LOC, that why `mPublisherAdView` be NULL

```
   mPublisherAdView = view.findViewById(R.id.publisherAdView);
```

should be

```
    mPublisherAdView = view.findViewById(R.id.banner_AdView);
```